# How to convert from float to int to string? invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'x'

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, csv

how convert float to int to string?

```
with open(DATA_DIR+'/test.csv', 'r') as inp:
reader = csv.DictReader(inp, delimiter=',',fieldnames = ['Id', 'Target'])
```

```
for row in csv.reader(inp):
```

```
text_file.write("Text "+str(int(row[1])))
```

Error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '323.0'`

Comment: `int(323.0)` makes no sense because there's a `.` in it. `int(float('323.0'))` would work better, because `float` is prepared to deal with commas/dots in your `str` evaluation, `int` is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x=Decimal(row[1]).normalize()
text_file.write(x)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The CSV parser is already reading the data that you are trying to convert as a string. That string has decimal point values which it won't convert to int. It will convert it to float though.

Here are 2 ways to do this:

1. Just split the string and use the integral part
2. in your example do `text_file.write('Text {:.0f}'.format(float(row[1]))`

With the 2nd approach you are basically converting it to float and thereafter you don't care for anything on the right of the decimal. So `.0f` indicates you don't want anything after the decimal including the `.`. More on this formatting can be learned in the link I pasted below.

As you dig deeper you should continue to use `type()` to identify the incoming data before you decide what to do with it.

ORIGINAL PART:
You don't have to convert the data to achieve what you want. At the end of it you want to write to a file as a string. If what you are getting from the csv is a float then you could simply format your string as

```
write_line = 'Text {:06.2f}'.format(row[1])
text_file.write(write_line)
```

Of course you could condense the two lines.
There is more info in python's docs - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'

Comment: Ok then print the type of the variable and also the content for your debugging purpose.
`print(type(row[1]))`

Comment: output: `<class 'str'> `

Comment: So `row[1]` is already a string. Just use it as it is instead of further converting twice.

Comment: 118.0 but I want save only 118

Comment: Updated my answer based on your clarifications. Take a look.

Answer (score -1):

Probably looks like row[1] is not having any numeric value. Can u specify what exactly it will hold?
Try printing row[i] before executing the int() function and see what value it is holding.

Comment: First row was bad. But I still have a problem.

Comment: 118.0 and I want to save as 118

Comment: Printing the row[i] will not necessarily clarify the data because the data was already a `str`. What was needed if at all was to find the `type`.